# How do I change light bulb on this type of ceiling fan?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, bulb

I am having trouble changing light bulbs of my ceiling fan pictured below. I took these images to home depot and no one could help me! I showed the fan to two handymen in-person and they couldn't figure it out either!
Please help me and show me a way to open the fixture for bulb changing.

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model? Is anything printed on it anywhere?

Comment: No! The only thing that says is "Made in Taiwan"

Answer (score 1):

It should be a counterclockwise twist off, by the ring it appears & just 1/4" **not anything like a 1/4-turn**. Sometimes they're really tight though. You want to twist in a sudden jerking motion rather than a slow torqueing like a light bulb.

If grip is an issue you can do pretty well with 2 short pieces of duct tape or any wide tape to use as handles...press-on one-half & let the other half hang down & then do your jerk action.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a quick sharp jerking motion with anything that's made of glass like the light shade appears to be in the photo -- if the metal ring comes loose and/or deforms the glass can fracture, leaving you with serious cuts. The idea of using duct tape is a good one, or you can use some rubber kitchen gloves that may give a better grip on the metal ring.

Comment: Thanks, I made my answer more precise. I see what you're saying, but the other way results in a lot of pressure on everything & the fan body just turns with you. I had to take a few completely down just to get them apart until I tried the jerking action. You want to use what little resistance the fan has & just pop it free. I frankly don't understand why they aren't spring-clipped or concealed set-screwed.

Comment: I am not sure but I have found a few that if turning CCW did not work. they needed to be pulled straght down and there were 3 or 4 wires that kept them in place. If it is this type when pushing back up push on the metal not the glass and try to push it up evenly. sometimes they take a couple of trys to get them to seat square.

Comment: My guess is that would've revealed itself already & hopefully they engineer these things in the future to something less problematic & more industry-wide. He does keep that puppy spotless though...I don't see a single spec anywhere.

Comment: a slightly damp latex glove will also help with better traction.

Comment: Yep, it just depends how stuck it is. Silly stuff to go through just to change a bulb.